# How to track changes with shared, immutable reference types in Javascript

Tags: javascript, immutability, change-tracking

Consider the following example:

```
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }

var collection = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3, 4]);
var consumerA = collection; // expects steady data
var consumerB = collection; // requires the latest data
var updatedCollection = collection.concat(5);

consumerA.reduce(add, 0); // 10 (desired result)
consumerB.reduce(add, 0); // 10 (incorrect result, should be 15)
```

`consumerA` operates with the immutable data it expects. What can be done in Javascript to ensure that `consumerB` always accesses the latest data?

Please notice: Just deep copying `consumerA` and treating `collection` as mutable data isn't an option.

**UPDATE:** The example merely serves to illustrate the fundamental problem, which is caused by shared reference types: Some consumers (or reference holder) rely on immutable, others on mutable data. I'm looking for a proper change tracking mechanism that solves this problem without undermining the benefits of immutable data.

Maybe the term "change tracking" is too vague. With change tracking I mean a way for `consumerB` to be informed about the change (push mechanism) or (more interesting) to be able to discover the change (pull mechanism). The latter would require that `consumerB` somehow gets access to the updated collection.

Comment: Make `consumerB` a deep copy of `collection`, then update `consumerB`.

Comment: @Cerbrus read the question.

Comment: The code behaves as I'd expect immutable types to behave.  Because its immutable, `collection.concat(5)` must not modify the collection, it must return a new collection with the added element.  Why would you expect `consumerB` to contain the added element?  It's a reference to the original collection.

Comment: Can the collection contain objects?  And are you concerned about changes to individual objects in the collection?

Comment: @Arg0n: I did. The OP only mentioned making `collection` mutable isn't an option.

Comment: @Amy: I don't expect that. My updated question should answer yours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's my only solution, but there are probably others. I wrap my immutable collection in a mutable object. A consumer which needs constant data holds a reference to the collection itself. A consumer which requires current state holds a reference to the wrapper. I use a primitive form of structural sharing in order to avoid cloning:

```
function add(x, y) { return x + y; }

var collection = Object.freeze([1, 2, 3, 4]);
var atom = {state: collection};
var consumerA = collection;
var consumerB = atom;

console.log(consumerA === consumerB.state); // true (obviously)

// naive structural sharing to avoid cloning
atom.state = Object.create(atom.state, {length: {value: atom.state.length, writable: true}});
atom.state.push(5);
Object.freeze(atom.state);

// as desired
console.log(consumerA.reduce(add, 0)); // 10
console.log(consumerB.state.reduce(add, 0)); // 15

// structural sharing is used
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(consumerB.state) === collection); // true

// object comparison simply by reference check
console.log(consumerA === consumerB.state); // false
```

By wrapping an immutable collection in a mutable wrapper it becomes a kind of persistent data type. That means it can be treated as a normal, mutable object but  leaves its previous versions untouched, hence persistent. By the way, to name the wrapper `atom` isn't an accident, but a reference to the corresponding data type in Clojure.

**Please note**: To use the prototype system for structural sharing can lead to memory leaking and should be used with caution only.

Answer (score 3):

You use `Object.freeze` when you declare  `collection`, so you can't added properties to `collection`.

When you create `consumerB`, you execute a copy of the object `collection`

```
var consumerB = collection;
```

So you can't added properties to `consumerB` like `collection`.

You need to clone the object instead copy it. You can do it like :

```
var consumerB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(collection));
```

Comment: Yeah, I want to avoid deep copying altogether. I'm looking for a proper change tracking mechanism.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: That's not possible. You can't have immutable objects _and_ mutable objects without deep copying. What you want can't be done.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I know what you mean. To update immutable data you always have to copy it. That's excatly what I'm doing with `collection.concat`. That's not what I mean. I rephrase my question accordingly.